# 'PathCollection' not iterable - creating a draggable scatter plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to create a Matplotlib scatter plot with draggable markers.

I found a draggable rectangle example on the Matplotlib site, https://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html.  The approach appears to be to create a DraggableRectangle class that handles the mouse events and which is initialized and connected for each rectangle in the bar plot.

I tried to do something similar with a scatter plot, but when I try to iterate through the markers I get a typeError: 'PathCollection' object is not iterable.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class DraggableMarker:

    def __init__(self, marker):
        self.marker = marker

    def connect(self):
        self.cidpress = self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
            'button_press_event', self.on_press)
        self.cidrelease = self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
            'button_release_event', self.on_release)
        self.cidmotion = self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
            'motion_notify_event', self.on_motion)

    def on_press(self, event):
        pass

    def on_motion(self, event):
        pass

    def on_release(self, event):
        pass

    def disconnect(self):
        self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidpress)
        self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidrelease)
        self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidmotion)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
markers = ax.scatter(np.random.rand(10), np.random.rand(10), marker ='o')

draggable_markers = []
for marker in markers:
    draggable_marker = DraggableMarker(marker)
    draggable_marker.connect()
    draggable_markers.append(draggable_marker)

plt.show()
```

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: A PathCollection will store the positions of its members inside of it. Those can be accessed via `get_offsets` and  `set_offsets`. In gneral, looking at https://matplotlib.org/gallery/event_handling/path_editor.html or https://matplotlib.org/gallery/event_handling/poly_editor.html may be more helpful here.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  It seems that get_offsets returns the x,y values based on the values of the chart, where my mouse button event is returning a pixel-based position.  So, I need to figure that out, but I'm making forward progress again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else comes across this in search of an answer, here is a draggable scatter based on the links provided in comments by ImportanceOfBeingErnes.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class DraggableScatter():

    epsilon = 5

    def __init__(self, scatter):

        self.scatter = scatter
        self._ind = None
        self.ax = scatter.axes
        self.canvas = self.ax.figure.canvas
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.button_press_callback)
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self.button_release_callback)
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.motion_notify_callback)
        plt.show()


    def get_ind_under_point(self, event):   
        xy = np.asarray(self.scatter.get_offsets())
        xyt = self.ax.transData.transform(xy)
        xt, yt = xyt[:, 0], xyt[:, 1]

        d = np.sqrt((xt - event.x)**2 + (yt - event.y)**2)
        ind = d.argmin()

        if d[ind] >= self.epsilon:
            ind = None

        return ind

    def button_press_callback(self, event):
        if event.inaxes is None:
            return
        if event.button != 1:
            return
        self._ind = self.get_ind_under_point(event)

    def button_release_callback(self, event):
        if event.button != 1:
            return
        self._ind = None

    def motion_notify_callback(self, event):
        if self._ind is None:
            return
        if event.inaxes is None:
            return
        if event.button != 1:
            return
        x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata
        xy = np.asarray(self.scatter.get_offsets())
        xy[self._ind] = np.array([x, y])        
        self.scatter.set_offsets(xy)
        self.canvas.draw_idle()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
scatter = ax.scatter(np.random.rand(10), np.random.rand(10), marker='o')

DraggableScatter(scatter)
```