# Draggable Matplotlib scatter with an animated plot using blitting

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I recently asked a question about creating a draggable scatter and with the help of someone I was able to come up with a working example. See ['PathCollection' not iterable - creating a draggable scatter plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52840767/pathcollection-not-iterable-creating-a-draggable-scatter-plot?noredirect=1#comment92598243_52840767).

I'm now trying to use the DraggableScatter class I created with an animated plot using blitting.

I've tried to attach the DraggableScatter class in multiple places, e.g., after initializing the scatter, in the init function and in the update function.  In the first cases, the DraggableScatter's scatter is empty, which makes sense but obviously doesn't work.  In the other two, the clicks seem not to be captured.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import numpy as np

class DraggableScatter():

    epsilon = 5

    def __init__(self, scatter):
        self.scatter = scatter
        self._ind = None
        self.ax = scatter.axes
        self.canvas = self.ax.figure.canvas
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.button_press_callback)
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self.button_release_callback)
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.motion_notify_callback)


    def get_ind_under_point(self, event):   
        xy = np.asarray(self.scatter.get_offsets())
        xyt = self.ax.transData.transform(xy)
        xt, yt = xyt[:, 0], xyt[:, 1]

        d = np.sqrt((xt - event.x)**2 + (yt - event.y)**2)
        ind = d.argmin()

        if d[ind] >= self.epsilon:
            ind = None

        return ind

    def button_press_callback(self, event):
        if event.inaxes is None:
            return
        if event.button != 1:
            return
        self._ind = self.get_ind_under_point(event)

    def button_release_callback(self, event):
        if event.button != 1:
            return
        self._ind = None

    def motion_notify_callback(self, event):
        if self._ind is None:
            return
        if event.inaxes is None:
            return
        if event.button != 1:
            return
        x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata
        xy = np.asarray(self.scatter.get_offsets())
        xy[self._ind] = np.array([x, y])        
        self.scatter.set_offsets(xy)
        self.canvas.draw_idle()


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
scatter = ax.scatter([],[])


def init():
    ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
    ax.set_ylim(0, 1)

    return scatter,

def update(frame):
    scatter = ax.scatter(np.random.rand(10), np.random.rand(10), marker ='o')
    ds = DraggableScatter(scatter)
    return scatter,

ani = FuncAnimation(fig=fig, func=update, init_func=init, blit=True, interval=5000)
plt.show()
```

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: You create a new scatter plot for each iteration. Is this really what you want? If so, blitting does not make too much sense and you can leave that out.

Comment: Yes, in this case, the blitting does not make much sense.  It's an artifact of simplifying the real code to an example for posting.

Comment: I think the only solution is to implement blitting and the animation yourself. Both should use the same function to blit and for the animation you can create a timer. A bit of logic is required to define what happens if you drag *while* the next animation step is performed.

Comment: Thanks, I may opt to forgo either blitting or animation for this one.  I'm already pushing my comfort zone with Matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

This works with the GTK3Cairo backend. (It does not work using TkAgg, Qt4Agg, Qt5Agg, GTK3Agg.)

Create the `DraggableScatter` once, then use `ds.scatter.set_offsets` to change the scatter point data inside the `update` function:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import numpy as np

class DraggableScatter():

    epsilon = 5

    def __init__(self, scatter):
        self.scatter = scatter
        self._ind = None
        self.ax = scatter.axes
        self.canvas = self.ax.figure.canvas
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.button_press_callback)
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self.button_release_callback)
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.motion_notify_callback)


    def get_ind_under_point(self, event):   
        xy = np.asarray(self.scatter.get_offsets())
        xyt = self.ax.transData.transform(xy)
        xt, yt = xyt[:, 0], xyt[:, 1]

        d = np.sqrt((xt - event.x)**2 + (yt - event.y)**2)
        ind = d.argmin()

        if d[ind] >= self.epsilon:
            ind = None

        return ind

    def button_press_callback(self, event):
        if event.inaxes is None:
            return
        if event.button != 1:
            return
        self._ind = self.get_ind_under_point(event)

    def button_release_callback(self, event):
        if event.button != 1:
            return
        self._ind = None

    def motion_notify_callback(self, event):
        if self._ind is None:
            return
        if event.inaxes is None:
            return
        if event.button != 1:
            return
        x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata
        xy = np.asarray(self.scatter.get_offsets())
        xy[self._ind] = np.array([x, y])        
        self.scatter.set_offsets(xy)
        self.canvas.draw_idle()


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
scatter = ax.scatter(np.random.rand(10), np.random.rand(10), marker ='o')
ds = DraggableScatter(scatter)

def init():
    ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
    ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
    return ds.scatter,

def update(frame, ds):
    x, y = np.random.rand(10), np.random.rand(10)
    ds.scatter.set_offsets(np.column_stack([x, y]))
    return ds.scatter,

ani = FuncAnimation(fig=fig, func=update, init_func=init, fargs=[ds], blit=True, 
                    interval=5000)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks @unutbu, that makes sense.  However, the draw_idle() call in motion_notify_callback seems to have no effect and as such, I can't see the marker being dragged.  Does the use of blitting mean that the plot is only refreshed when the update function is called?

Comment: @Chris: The code I posted works fine for me. There shouldn't be a problem both blitting and calling `draw_idle`. AFAICS there is no error in the code. If it isn't working for you, one thing you might try is a different [backend](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend). The animation window, GUI and widgets all depend on the backend, and sometimes backends each behave a little differently.

Comment: thanks for confirming; I'll try it with a different backend

Comment: The code does not work. It will throw an error because `init` does not return any artist, which is required for blitting to work correctly. However if you actually let the `init` function return an artist, this will let the animation run fine, which in turn means that you cannot drag the scatters any more.

Comment: Yes, `__init__` should return `ds.scatter`. After editing the code to do so, the code still runs without error and I am able to drag points about.